# str_replace in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin

I want to do a `str_replace` whenever the WordPress admin loads. I thought using the `admin_head` action might work but I haven't had any luck.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. What are you trying to achieve? Please add details to your question, the hook you need may vary depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of admin-page filters you can use. Without knowing exactly what you want to do, this page might be a starting point for you. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Administrative_Filters

Good luck!